# Firebase trouble reading lists

Tags: firebase

The tutorial I'm following here https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#tutorial/basic/5 says that for lists you can push a new item like this...

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase("https://.../items"
myDataRef.push({name: "Sally"});
```

The docs say here https://www.firebase.com/docs/managing-lists.html that to read list data just do something like this

```
myDataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

snapshot.val() gives back an object with random keys that contain my objects.  Do I really have to do something like

```
arr =[] Object.keys(snapshot.val()).forEach(function(key) { arr.push(snapshot.val()[key])})
```

to get a normal looking array of objects? or am I missing something here..  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but see if this helps to retrieve the data you're looking for with snapshot.val().Use child_added, this will go down the endpoint("firebase_url/items") and show each immediate object.

```
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Check out this link to get more info on reading from firebase, http://www.firebase.com/docs/reading-data.html

Comment: Be sure to check `prevChild` here, which is passed along with `snapshot` into the callback; the order of the values is not guaranteed here (although it's correct as long as concurrent edits are not taking place during the read).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects are not ordered. So the keys may appear in different order than your data (JSON can put them anywhere it pleases). To iterate them in order, try [forEach](https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/datasnapshot/foreach.html):

```
myDataRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(ss) {
     console.log(ss.name());
  });
});
```

For more real-time results, Ron's example using child_added is ideal.